# How to calculate average based on distinct counts in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

My SSAS cube has the following fact and dimensions with the columns as shown below

### FactActivity

DateKey, UserKey, ActivityKey, ActivityCount

### DimDate

DateKey, Date, Week, Year

### DimUser

UserKey, UserName, Gender

### DimActivity

ActivityKey, ActivityName

I have created the distinct count measures of users and dates as follows

### [Distinct Users]

COUNT(NONEMPTY([DimUser].[UserKey].[UserKey].Members, [Measures].[ActivityCount])

### [Distinct Dates]

COUNT(NONEMPTY([DimDate].[DateKey].[DateKey].Members, [Measures].[ActivityCount])

Both these measures are working correctly as expected when I slice/pivot by ActivityName.

Now I wanted to calculate average days per user, so I created the metric as follows

### [Avg Days Per User]

AVG([DimUser].[UserKey].[UserKey].Members, [Measures].[Distinct Dates])

But this is giving me wrong results.! i also tried

DIVIDE([Measures].[Distinct Days], [Measures].[Distinct Users])

Still I get wrong results...what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just adding in `EXISTING` will help?

```
AVG(
  EXISTING [DimUser].[UserKey].[UserKey].Members, 
  [Measures].[Distinct Dates]
)
```

Although trying to recreate something similar in AdvWks I seem top get a valid return without `EXISTING`:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Avg Count Per Reseller] AS 
    Avg
    ( [Reseller].[Reseller].[Reseller].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[Reseller Order Count]
    ), format_string = "0.0000" 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Reseller Order Count],[Measures].[Avg Count Per Reseller]} ON 0
 ,{[Promotion].[Promotion].[All Promotions].Children} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2005];
```